# Pandas groupby cut sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bin a column and take the sum for rows that satisfy an indexing condition.

Here is an example of the kind of DataFrame I'm working with:

```py
df 

A    B    C    D
a    aa   0    1
a    aa   1    2
a    aa   2    10
a    bb   0    4
a    bb   1    5
a    bb   2    60
b    aa   0    7
b    aa   1    8
b    aa   2    90
b    bb   0    10
b    bb   1    11
b    bb   2    12
```

What I'd like to do is first bin the column of features `C` (ie `0,1` is `f0` and `2` is `f1`) and sum the values in column `D` within each bin and still keep the respective `A` and B` index pairs intact. The result of which would look like:

```py
A    B    C    D
a    aa   f0   3
a    aa   f1   10
a    bb   f0   9
a    bb   f1   60
b    aa   f0   15
b    aa   f1   90
b    bb   f0   21
b    bb   f1   12
```

I've done the binning using `pandas.cut` like so:

```
cut = pd.cut(df['C'], bins=[0,2,3], right=False, labels=['f0','f1'])
```

But I am having trouble keeping maintaining the index pairs (columns `A,B`) intact using `df.groupby(cut)` and I would like to not have to iterate through all possible `(A,B)` pairs and bin + sum them myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it sounds like you should add the A and B columns to your groupby statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the additional columns that define your desired groups into your groupby statement:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas

df = pandas.read_table(StringIO("""\
A    B    C    D
a    aa   0    1
a    aa   1    2
a    aa   2    10
a    bb   0    4
a    bb   1    5
a    bb   2    60
b    aa   0    7
b    aa   1    8
b    aa   2    90
b    bb   0    10
b    bb   1    11
b    bb   2    12"""), sep='\s+')

output = (
    df.assign(C=pandas.cut(df['C'], bins=[0,2,3], right=False, labels=['f0','f1']))
      .groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False)  
      .sum()  
)
```

```
 A   B   C   D
 a  aa  f0   3
 a  aa  f1  10
 a  bb  f0   9
 a  bb  f1  60
 b  aa  f0  15
 b  aa  f1  90
 b  bb  f0  21
 b  bb  f1  12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `groupby` on `['A','B','C']` after reassigning the values in `C`:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['C'].isin([0,1]), 'f0', 'f1')
df = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  a  aa  f0   3
1  a  aa  f1  10
2  a  bb  f0   9
3  a  bb  f1  60
4  b  aa  f0  15
5  b  aa  f1  90
6  b  bb  f0  21
7  b  bb  f1  12
```